# Django pagination with no primary key

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have this function in views.py  that will display all categories in a research management system following several tutorials:

```
def CategoryView(request):
    cat_menu=Category.objects.all();
    return render(request, 'Category.html',{'cat_menu':cat_menu})
```

When a user clicks on a category, they will get all the research papers that are under this category

**Views.py**

```
def ResearchCategoryView(request,cats):


    category_research=ResearchesList.objects.filter(research_category=cats.replace('_',' '))
    paginator=Paginator(category_research,1)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page',1)
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request,'Researches-Guest.html',{'cats':cats.title().replace('_',' '),'category_research':category_research,'page_obj':page_obj,})
```

I would like to add a paginator to ResearchCategoryView, except I can't link to the same url as the

category is not a primary key in the research table.
Is there a way to do this without having to rewrite ResearchCategoryView?

**urls.py**

```
path('',views.GuestHome,name="GuestHome"),
path('FeedBackForm',views.Form2,name="FeedBackForm"),
path('FeedBackRecieved',views.ThankYou,name="ThankYou"),
path('Category/',CategoryView,name='Categorys'),
path('Category/<str:cats>',ResearchCategoryView,name='researchcategory'),
path('Category/cats',ResearchCategoryView,name='researchcategory2'),
path('Research/<int:pk>',AbstractView.as_view(),name='abstract'),
path('search_research', views.search_research, name='search_research'),
```

** models.py inspected from mySQL**

```
class ResearchesList(models.Model):
    research_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.TextField()
    auther = models.TextField()
    auther1 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    auther2 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    auther3 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    auther4 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    auther5 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    auther6 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    abstract = models.TextField()
    publish_date = models.DateField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    finish_date = models.DateField()
    research_url = models.TextField()
    journal_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    research_category = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    data_type = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    data_source = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    geo_area = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    is_collected_via_socialmedia = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    collecation_start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    finishing_colleaction_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_the_data = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sample_size = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sampling_method = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    data_collecation = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    data_analysis = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    write_up = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    publication = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    capcity_of_building = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    varisble_and_data_dic_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    actual_data_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    name_of_the_file = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    file_format = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    lesson_learnt = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    other_comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_this_data_public = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    user_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='user-id', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'researches_list'



class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=70)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'category'
```

**Researches-Guest.html**

```
<table class="table table-hover p-table">

                      {% if category_research%}

                          {%for item in category_research%}

                      {% if item.status == "Approved" %}

                          <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <td class="p-name">
                                  <a href="{% url 'abstract' item.pk%}">{{item.title}}</a> by {{item.auther1}},  {{item.auther2}},  {{item.auther3}}, {{item.auther4}},{{item.auther5}},{{item.auther6}}
                                  <br>
                                  <small> Published by:{{item.auther}}  Publising date:{{item.publish_date}}</small>
                              </td>
                          </tr>


                          </tbody>

                      {% endif %}

                       {% endfor%}
                      {%else%}
                        <h2>This Category doesn't exist</h2>
                      {%endif%}
                  </table>
{% if page_obj.has_previous%}
                  <span class=pull-left">

                  <a href="#"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Previous</button></a>

                    </span>
                   {% endif %}
                  {% if page_obj.has_next%}
                   <span class="pull-right">

                  <a href="#"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Next</button></a>

                   </span>
                        {% endif %}
```

**Category.html**

```
{%for item in cat_menu%}
                <table class="table">

                              <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>
                                        <a href="{% url 'researchcategory' item.category_name%}">{{item.category_name}}</a>
                                  </td>

                              </tr>

                              </tbody>
                          </table>
              {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What prevents you from having the ResearchesList filtered on the category, then ordered by the primary key for the pagination?

Comment: @schillingt I did exactly that in ResearchCategoryView. My main issue right now is that I don't know which url to direct to in the next and previous buttons in pagination since the url for the page uses the primery key of the category model, but the research display page uses the ResearchesList model which doesn't have category as its primary key. I'm probably misunderstanding something, may you elaborate more? example: category page url in browser (this will display the categories): ` 127.0.0.1:8000/Category ' After choosing a category ` 127.0.0.1:8000/Category/Clinical%20Science

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a querystring parameter that indicates which page  you're on? 127.0.0.1:8000/Category/Clinical%20Science?page=4

Comment: @ schillingt I get a NoReverseMatch error when clicking on next/ previous when provided with the href link that normally takes the user to the research page. ` {% url 'researchcategory' item.category_name%}` alongside `?page={{page_obj.next_page_number}}` . I know why I'm getting this error as the Research_Guest.html doesn't use the category model and thus doesn't have Category_name as its primary key so I wonder what I should have here instead.
if you could provide some explanation for queryString parameter  that would also be appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `item.category_name` for that error?

Comment: @schillingt  In Category.html -which uses the category model-, the list of available categories will be displayed. Clicking on one category will take the user to the list of researches that fall under this category. The URL I posted  which contains `item.category_name` is in the category.html. That is what will take the user to the research page which works well without pagination so consider it equal to Clinical science for now

Comment: If you browse to that view, then append `?page=2` does it render a 404? If it's a 200 response, then the problem is in that `{% url ` call. I think using a proper `SlugField` would make this easier for you.